# CakePHP - Session in Console?

Tags: cakephp

I write a CLI API for my Application which sends E-Mails. For sending different languages i tried changing the current language in the session (which works fine in a different controller) but in the CLI it prints:

```
Fatal Error Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object
```

Which remains to

```
$currentLang = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
```

Any way to use the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no component or helper for CLI.
If one needs the session (for testing!), one would use CakeSession::read().

Note: session is something web-frontend-based and you never need it in CLI as there is no way to actually handle sessions there. You need to use a different env() based approach there.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to set language for translation __() then?

Comment: Configure::write() - as [documented](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#internationalizing-your-application).

Comment: why this method (CakeSession::read()) is not recommended? i am trying to make session status using websocket and websocket interface is in CLI (backend)..and of course i want to know how the session is going

Comment: I strongly dislike when someone says you *never* need something, because in the infinity of possible scenarios, there is bound to be at least *one* where it makes perfect sense. For example, I have a situation where I have reams of Web-based code, much of which use sessions to get logged-in user data, and I'd like to use that code in a Shell program without re-writing everything. (**DRY** remember?) The solution is to either dummy up the "$_SESSION" variable in the Shell program, or use *CakeSession::write()*, as suggested (although I haven't tried that one yet).